# What chemical test can differentiate secondary and tertiary alcohols?

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, alcohols

I have to perform a chemical test to determine whether the solution is a secondary or a tertiary alcohol. How can I do this? Please explain the procedure and the apparatus.

Answer (score 5):

Or you can try the very simple [Lucas' test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%27_reagent) using zinc chloride and concentrated hydrochloric acid:
$$\ce{ROH + HCl -> RCl + H2O}$$

It works best with tertiary alkohols, slow with secondary alcohols and not at all with primary alcohols.

Answer (score 3):

- Add sulfuric acid to a chilled aqueous solution of the alcohol and sodium nitrite.
- Record the UV spectrum.

Tertiary alkyl nitrites show an absorption band at $\lambda$ = 400 nm, secondary and primary alkyl nitrites only below.

Answer (score 1):

A secondary alcohol can be further oxidized to a ketone ([reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxidation_of_secondary_alcohols_to_ketones)), while a tertiary alcohol cannot. For example, when you use dichromate as oxidation agent, you will observe a color change of the solution from orange to green. A tertiary alcohol will not react unless your oxidizer is too concentrated.